# How long does it take for the debuffs from Red's Wings to start?

Tags: terraria, terraria-mobile

I've been on Terraria for about 2 months and I have came across a nice pair of wings- reds wings. I put them on and nothing happened, so I was wondering how long until the debuffs may start.

Comment: What do you mean by debuffs? None of the wings in Terraria give you a debuff (except the developer wings that can only be worn by a dev, they will kill anyone else) http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Wings

Comment: @DBS It looks like OP was referring to Red's Wings. The question was edited for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the wings don't affect players in the console, and in the mobile, so if you are using the wings on XBox, PS, iOS, etc., it doesn't give you effects, which means you can use them all you want.